# How to correctly link an external library using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cryptography, rsa, chilkat

I'm trying to use the Chilkat C++ library to do a cryptography assignment, but I cannot seem to get the library to link properly. As of right now the header file CkRsa.h cannot be found by the compiler. I've spent a few hours searching across the internet for solutions to no avail. Here is what I have so far (this is all in a Mac OS X environment):

The lib files are installed in /users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/libDyn and the header files are in /users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(SocketEncryption)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_library(chilkat STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(
        TARGET chilkat
        PROPERTY
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/libDyn/libchilkat_x86_64.dylib"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include"
)
add_executable(SocketEncryption ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(SocketEncryption chilkat)
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CkRsa.h>
//#include <CkPrivateKey.h>
//#include <CkSocket.h>

int main() {
    CkRsa alice;
    CkRsa bob;

    // Key Generation
    bool success = alice.GenerateKey(1024);
    const char *alicePublicKey = alice.exportPublicKey();
    const char *alicePrivateKey = alice.exportPrivateKey();
    const char *aliceMessage = "Hi, Bob. How are you?";

    // Encryption Step
    std::cout << "Encryption started." << std::endl;
    CkRsa rsaEncryptor;
    rsaEncryptor.put_EncodingMode("hex");
    success = rsaEncryptor.ImportPublicKey(alicePublicKey);
    bool usePrivateKey = false;
    const char * ciphertext = rsaEncryptor.encryptStringENC(aliceMessage, success);
    std::cout << ciphertext << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be in `/usr/include/` directory.

Comment: How would I change the CMakeList.txt to reflect this?

Comment: Assuming you have a file `/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include/CkRsa.h` this should work.

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this (quotation):

```
include_directories("/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include")
link_directories("/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/libDyn")
```

Comment: Just did this, it is still not correctly including the CkRsa.h file

Comment: copy header and lib directory into your directory (your access right). and try relative path like   include_directories("../chilkat/include") etc.

Comment: would this directory be /usr ? not sure where these should go

Comment: /home/JustAnotherStudentDev note that chmod 755

Comment: I'm in an OS X environment, I do not have this folder

Comment: then copy the directory  into your project directory, and include_directories("./chilkat/include")

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simply problem of how you ordered your calls. CMake does parse its scripts sequential. So the `include_directories()` call has to be put before the `add_executable()` call:

```
include_directories("/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include")
add_executable(SocketEncryption ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

The better way since CMake 2.8.12 would be to let the library propagate its header file paths:

```
target_include_directories(chilkat PUBLIC "/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include")
```

Or - for readability - add it directly via target properties:

```
set_property(
    TARGET chilkat 
    PROPERTY 
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/libDyn/libchilkat_x86_64.dylib"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include"
)
```

See also [CMake: Creating Relocatable Packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-relocatable-packages).

**References**

- [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)
- [How is CMake used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007566/how-is-cmake-used/)
- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)

Comment: I updated the CMakeLists.txt to reflect this, but it still is not working properly. Does anything seem missing or out of place? I updated it in the question

Comment: @JustAnotherStudentDev What does `find_file(_header_path "CkRsa.h" PATHS "/users/Adam/Desktop/chilkat/include")`|`message("_header_path = ${_header_path}")` return? Can you please also add the error message(s) from your compiler to your answer?